# Сосредотачивать или сосредоточивать?

Tags: орфография

Насколько я понимаю, обе формы - и "сосредотачивать" и "сосредоточивать" являются правильными (даже Ворд ни одну из них не подчеркивает). Но в чем разница между этими словами? По логике правильно говорить "сосредоточивать" - от "сосредотОчить". Но, может быть, между обоими словами есть какое-то смысловое различие?
Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 7):

В русском языке параллельно используются варианты "сосредоточивать - сосредотачивать". Форма с ***о*** является книжной, форма с ***а***  - разговорной. Еще варианты: обусловливать - обуславливать, уполномочивать - уполномачивать. Для некоторых пар форма на ***о*** устарела (оспоривать - устар., оспаривать - общеупотребит. Ср.: "Хвалу и клевету приемли равнодушно, и не осп**о**ривай глупца" — Пушкин).